# How to trigger Github Workflow after a check suite finishes?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I want to trigger a workflow only if a particular workflow finishes... does anyone know how to do that?

Some context:

- I have a workflow `Tests` and another called `Build-feature`.
- I run my `Tests` workflow on every PR to branch `feature`.
- If something is pushed/merged to branch `feature` then i want to run workflow `Tests` and only if that succeeds then i want to run `Build-feature` workflow.

Also there's the event `check_suite` that it's supposed to trigger a workflow: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#check-suite-event-check_suite

I tried this example:

```
on:
  check_suite:
    types: [rerequested, completed]
```

But my workflow never triggers, any ideas why? or any other idea on how can i achieve the above?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Turns out that you can achieve that using the `on: status` event, but you need to manually trigger the status with a token that is not [the one from the Github Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/authenticating-with-the-github_token).

You need to add something like this in order to trigger the status event after a workflow finishes:

```
      - name: Trigger status event
        run: >-
          curl -L -X POST 
          -H "Content-Type: application/json"
          -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_PAT}}"
          -d '{
            "state": "success",
            "target_url": "https://you-can-add-a.url/",
            "description": "All tests passed", "context": "your-custom/status-event"
          }'
          "https://api.github.com/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/statuses/${GITHUB_SHA}"
```

And in your other workflow you can just add an `if` condition in case you have more than one status event that can trigger the workflow, something like this:

```
on: status

...

jobs:

...

  if: github.event.context == 'your-custom/status-event'
```

And that's it... That's how you can chain workflows.

**Old answer:**

Well, after asking at the github.community forum i got an answer.

> Events raised from the Actions app do not trigger workflows.  This restriction is currently in place in order to prevent a circular workflow execution.

Related links:

- https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/on-check-suite-never-gets-called/td-p/38955
- https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/on-check-suite-never-triggers-why/m-p/42891/highlight/false#M5162

Edit:
The same applies to `check` events.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use [steps](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps). The "build" step is only executed if the previous "Test" step was successful.

If you really need to model it via jobs, than you can use [needs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds).

Example:

```
jobs:
  job1:
  job2:
    needs: job1
  job3:
    needs: [job1, job2]
```

The check_suite event is only triggered by (external) integrations, like Netlify builds. Note: the event is also only triggered, if you workflow is already merged to your default branch (master).

Comment: Since i want to use the same `Test` on different conditions, i don't want to copy & paste my whole `test.yml` workflow file into the different workflows.

For example, i want to have a main `Build` workflow and a `Build-feature` workflow, but i want the same `Test` workflow to run before any of the builds run.

That's why the jobs is not what i want, because i will need to add the test jobs to 2 different files and will be harder to maintain.