# How can I trigger a git action after completion of a Jenkins Job?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, github-actions

New to CI/CD Integration. I want to trigger a Git Action after a Jenkins Job ("Example Jenkins Job") already configured in my CI/CD pipeline completes. I do not want to trigger the action from the jenkins script itself.

I've looked at [Github Actions - trigger another action after one action is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750603/github-actions-trigger-another-action-after-one-action-is-completed), but my question differs as the desire is to trigger the action only after the successful completion of my Jenkins Job, not another Git Action.

Are there any examples of how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can send HTTP Request from jenkins to trigger github action - https://dev.to/rikurouvila/how-to-trigger-a-github-action-with-an-htt-request-545

Comment: Thanks but I don’t want to trigger the action from Jenkins

Comment: Pipeline runs in github are called "Checks" and "Statuses". This topic should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59595803/how-to-trigger-github-workflow-after-a-check-suite-finishes